# Laravel: JSON data in view blade

Tags: php, json, laravel, view, laravel-blade

Controller:

```
$commission = Commission::findOrFail($id);

    $json_calculation = (array) json_decode($commission->price_calculation, true);

    return view('tradesman.commissions-list-detail')
        ->with('commission', $commission)
        ->with('calculations', $json_calculation);
```

JSON:

```
{"price_per_hour":"180","hours":"4","material_type_1":"Something","material_price_1":"1200","material_type_2":"Something","material_price_2":"800"}
```

View:

```
@forelse($calculations as $calculation)
                <p>{!! $calculation->price_per_hour !!}</p>
```

Error:

```
ErrorException: Trying to get property of non-object
```

If i use just {!! $calculation !!} it works but i need something like {!! $calculation->material_type1 !!}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are converting your Json into Array, that's you would not able to access your key like object. So change your this line

```
$json_calculation = (array) json_decode($commission->price_calculation, true);
```

like this and then try. it will decode your json like object

```
$json_calculation = json_decode($commission->price_calculation);
```